# Django change frontend validation of number input widget

Tags: python, django

For number fields in the Django admin interface, it's only possible to input numbers and separators. How can I implement a similar frontend validation for my own custom widget? For example, I want to extend a TextInput widget so that the user can only input [A-Za-z]. The included `pattern` attribute only validates in the backend.

Comment: I suggest you tu use javascript front end validation for that

Comment: That's probably very convoluted, as I'm not even using custom templates for my admin interface. Is there no easier way?

Comment: I'm afraid you will need to learn about front-end languages if you intend to build a web app, at least a bit of js and css